# how to select a string from array key that has 2 values

Tags: php, mysql

So I select 2 usernames from the database
var_dump($result); gives me the following:

```
array(6) { 
  ["first_name"]=> string(5) "First" 
  [0]=> string(5) "First2" 
  ["last_name"]=> string(7) "Last" 
  [1]=> string(6) "Last2" 
  [2]=> string(5) "First" 
  [3]=> string(7) "Last" 
}
```

How can I select First and First2 seperatly
$result['first_name'] returns Jetse

How to select First 2?

Comment: You're going to have to show some of your own code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$result['first_name']; // First
$result[0]; // First2
```